# Highcharts data set array

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a chart in highcharts and i'm experiencing trouble passing through data. Right now the problem is the graph is completely vertical, and it is receiving the wrong points for the graph. Its saying its totals are 80, and 2011. The totals are supposed to be 50, and 80.

```
var myarrays = [2011, 1, 12, 50, 2011, 2, 13, 80];

data:

             (function () {

             var data = [];

             for (var i = 0; i < myarrays.length; i++)
             {
                data.push(myarrays[i], myarrays[i + 1], myarrays[i+2], myarrays[i+3]);
                i+2;
             }
             return data;

             }())
```

The out put is supposed to return, two sets because the series takes in 4 parameters,

```
[2011, 1, 12, 50]
[2011, 2, 13, 80]
```

Also when i manually pass in variables, the format that seems to work is
    [[Date.UTC(2011, 7, 11), 101]

So is there any way to turn the return to the above format?

```js
var myarrays = [2011, 1, 12, 50, 2011, 2, 13, 80];

$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: 'spline',
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'MySeries',
      data:
        (function() {

          var data = [];

          for (var i = 0; i < myarrays.length; i++) {
            data.push(myarrays[i], myarrays[i + 1], myarrays[i + 2], myarrays[i + 3]);
            i +=3;
          }
          return data;
        }]
    });
  )]);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var myarrays = [[2011, 1, 12, 50], [2011, 2, 13, 80]];` ?

Comment: Changing it to that just make a 2 show up on the graph

Answer (score 0):

A data can be provided to the spline series in the following forms...

```
data = [y1, y2, ..., yn];
data = [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ..., [xn, yn];
data = [[name1, y1], [name2, y2], ..., [namen, yn]];
data = [{x: x1, y: y1}, {x: x1, y: y2}, ... {x: xn, y: y2}];
```

where x and y values are numbers and name values are strings. If x values are not included then the x values are automately calculated starting at 0 and incrementing by 1.

In your example, the myarray has the form [year1, month1, day1, total1, year2, month2, day2, total2, ...] where every four values represent a single data point in the chart. You need to combine the year, month, and day values into a single number or string value which will then be used as the x or name value for the data point. The total value will be used as the y value for the data point. The code might then look something like...

```
var myarrays = [2011, 1, 12, 50, 2011, 2, 13, 80];

$(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'MySeries',
            data: (function() {
                var data = [];
                for (var i = 0; i + 3 < myarrays.length; i += 4) {
                    var name = myarrays[i] + "/" + myarrays[i + 1] + "/" + myarrays[i + 2];
                    var y = myarrays[i+3];
                    data.push([name, y]);
                }
                return data;
            })()
        }]
    });
});
```